# How would I count up to f on an arduino

Tags: hex, arduino, counting

Lets say you want to have 16 different numbers instead of 10 for your Arduino.

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f

Look familiar? Yes, I want to make a hexadecimal counting script for the Arduino. Maybe it could count up to 40 characters of scrolling and random text that could be viewed on an LCD Screen (I already have the LCD part down).

I've searched just about everywhere for this and I haven't found a thing. Well, I actually did, but it didn't help this problem any. You can find the link here : http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php?topic=40555.0

I want the output to count from 0 to (40 f's).

I have an Arduino Uno and an LCD Screen (16x2) and I realize I might have to get a bigger screen.

Thank you for your time in reading this and I hope this problem gets solved!

Comment: what does this have to do with being on an arduino? counting 1-F in hex is the same in pretty much every language you care to code in...

Comment: It's not at all clear where you're stuck here.  What language do you intend to use?  Do you know how to display *anything* on the screen?  Do you understand hexadecimal?  Basically, what is the **specific** technical issue preventing you from progressing here?

Comment: See http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php?topic=8124.0

Comment: I am using the Arduino C language, and I sort of understand the hexadecimal type... But the real issue is that I don't know all of the functions for this type of program. I can display stuff on the LCD screen from variables, BUT I need the variable in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the [LiquidCrystal](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/LiquidCrystalPrint) library you can spesify in what base to print your number

```
a = 15;
lcd.print(a,HEX); //print E
```

BTW, it can be applied to the Serial object as well, for instance

```
b = 14;
Serial.println(b,HEX) //prints D
```

Looping

```
for( int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++)
   lcd.print(i,HEX);
```

this will print:

```
0 1 2 3 .... 9 A B C D E F 10 11 ... 1E 1F 20 21 22 ..... 2E 2F 30 ...
```

Comment: What would happen if you wanted to cycle through those numbers though? Would it be the same?

Comment: what do you mean by cycling through the numbers?

Comment: If I start at 0 then wait for one second then do the next number -- not predefined like you have it but a series of numbers like 1 through 2a(38 numbers) without predefining them all.

Comment: It will work just fine. you have to remember that the Arduino counts in binary, when it prints it, it is converted to the desired radix.

Comment: I've added an example

Comment: Oh I see now! Now time for some calculating.... 16x40=... so I would need 640 numbers? Interesting... Thank you for informing me of this converting thing!